# information about RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

I want information about RDLC.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDLC is a reporting platform for .net based apps - it can be used for both ASP.net as well as winform apps. Reports that are data driven (for eg financial statements) are well suited to be drawn in RDLC.

RDLC supports paging, custom headers/footers, tabular data (with options to repeat column headers on different pages) etc. - basically all the routine stuff you would like a reporting platform to handle. Export to pdf works fine, but for me, export to Excel kind-of sucked.